# Need help with CAML Query

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

This is my first time using CAML Query.

I have a query builder which I can test with.

I'm trying to create a query that will look for a specific string of text in the "Title" column, and find the date "Created" less than equal to -180 days, and find "StatusPreSales" column equal to "Completed"

Title = Single Line Text
Created = Date/Time
StatusPreSales = Choice (DropDown)

```
<Query>
<Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Title"></FieldRef>
      <Value Type="Text">Schust Engineering</Value>
    </Eq>
    <Leq>
      <FieldRef Name="Created" />
      <Value Type="DateTime">
      <Today OffsetDays="-180" />
      </Value>
    </Leq>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="StatusPreSales" />
      <Value Type="Choice">Completed</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
</Query>
```

This is the code I have but It doesn't seem to be filtering the date correctly or picking up the value of StatusPreSales column.

Does anyone know what i can do to fix my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are missing `<And>` and also I think the date should be `<Geq>`.

Example of date CAML Query:

```
<Where>
<Geq>
    <FieldRef Name="Created" />
    <Value Type="DateTime">
        <Today OffsetDays="-180" />
    </Value>
</Geq>
```

The above code would get all items which were created in the last 180 days.

The full query should be:

```
<Query>
<Where>
 <And>
  <And>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Title"></FieldRef>
      <Value Type="Text">Schust Engineering</Value>
    </Eq>
    <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name="Created" />
      <Value Type="DateTime">
      <Today OffsetDays="-180" />
      </Value>
    </Geq>
  </And>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="StatusPreSales" />
      <Value Type="Choice">Completed</Value>
    </Eq>
  </ANd>
 </Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: I'm using Leq to get items created before 180 days. Ultimately what I Plan to do is use the CAML Query in a PowerShell Script to recreate list items in another list that the query finds and then delete the items from the existing list.